# Who were the original Seven Deadly Sins?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In *Seven Deadly Sins*, Diane is 750 years old, and Ban and Escanor are under 50. 3000 years ago the Ten Commandments were beaten by the Seven Deadly Sins, so my question is, **who were the original Seven Deadly Sins?** Since Ban, Escanor and Diane weren't alive back then?

Comment: Where do you see that it was the seven deadly sins who beat them 3000 years before the current series?

Answer (score 3):

There weren't any others, meliodas created the sins and they all just came together I believe, and the SDS were NOT around 3000 years ago, they were made when meliodas became a holy knight. ( I haven't seen SDS in a while, but I finished the manga and I'm almost sure I'm right)

Comment: After thinking about it I think it is mentioned in the manga that premonition had a premenation about the creation of the seven deadly sins

Comment: yep, it was king of Lioness, who had a vision about Sins and Merlin found them based on the vision

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to when Meliodas said he created the sins to defeat the commandments. He meant now. It was him glauximia, drole, and a member of the goddess race that fought 3000 years ago. Also king MAY have been alive but he would have been way too young and way to weak.